# Netlify deploy Error: Cannot find module 'gatsby-plugin-image/graphql-utils'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gatsby, netlify, gatsby-plugin

I tried deploying a site to Netlify but ran into this error

```
10:22:38 PM:   Error: Cannot find module 'gatsby-plugin-image/graphql-utils'
```

I checked on here and saw a solution to run this command

```
node -v > nvmrc
```

I ran the command and started a fresh deployment. During deployment another error came up

```
10:29:38 PM: Build ready to start
10:29:40 PM: build-image version: e4d2dbe4cfec46db257e869258461ded89b75c9b
10:29:40 PM: build-image tag: v3.7.3
10:29:40 PM: buildbot version: 2cb5794cb93042dadefe5dbdc6b35edc34c20454
10:29:40 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
10:29:40 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
10:29:40 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
10:29:40 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
10:29:40 PM: git clone https://github.com/Dayropo/gatsby-exercise
10:29:41 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
10:29:42 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
10:29:43 PM: Different publish path detected, going to use the one specified in the Netlify configuration file: 'public' versus 'public/' in the Netlify UI
10:29:43 PM: Starting build script
10:29:43 PM: Installing dependencies
10:29:43 PM: Python version set to 2.7
10:29:43 PM: Attempting node version 'v14.16.1
' from .nvmrc
10:29:44 PM: Version 'v14.16.1
' not found - try `nvm ls-remote` to browse available versions.
10:29:44 PM: Failed to install node version 'v14.16.1
'
10:29:44 PM: Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
10:29:44 PM: Creating deploy upload records
10:29:44 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
10:29:44 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
10:29:44 PM: Finished processing build request in 4.627825827s
```

Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, when some dependency fails only in Netlify side, the 99% of the cases is caused by a missmatching versions of Node versions between local and Netlify environment. This is fixed by forcing the node version with:

```
node -v > nvmrc
```

When Netlify finds the `.nvmrc` file, it tries to download the version to start the building process, that's the perfect workaround and the way to fix missing dependencies. In your case, the Node version couldn't be satisfied (`14.16.1`) so the whole process can't even start.

Netlify's deploy system downloads Node and Node packages during build time and this issue is mostly related to a temporary issue between Netlify and Cloudflare.

So, if your application builds locally without any issues don't panic, they will fix the issue soon. Retry the deployment in a few hours and check the [Netlify status page](https://www.netlifystatus.com/) or [Cloudflare status page](https://www.cloudflarestatus.com/) for further logs.

According to Cloudflare status page, they seem to have troubles in some servers around the globe.

Sources:

- https://answers.netlify.com/t/need-help-debugging-version-12-18-0-not-found-try-nvm-ls-remote-to-browse-available-versions/19067/13
- https://answers.netlify.com/t/deploy-failed-to-install-node-version-10/7322/3
- https://github.com/netlify/cli/issues/1163
- https://answers.netlify.com/t/building-issue-version-12-18-0-not-found-try-nvm-ls-remote-to-browse-available-versions/21630

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sadly I'm still getting the same outcome

Comment: Try upgrading or downgrading the Node version

Comment: I've downgraded several times, still the same result. Last version I downgraded to was v12.18.0

Comment: The issue still the same but changing the version promoted, isn't it?